# need help regarding Markerless example using opencv for unity

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am working on project which is based on markerless technology so for this right now I am using opencv for unity and well known unity asset "Markerless example using opencv for unity" so after importing both packages it's showing one error of coremodule. I tried as much as i can but now I need help so i can proceed further to achieve my target.
here I am attaching the error that i am getting!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFgcs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the plugin not successfully installed or imported or you're using outdated. Because new update of opencv for unity is just awesome. Do import it again or else you need to manually import classes by going to core module.

Comment: Yes I just tried new version of it and that version contains the updated classes..
thank you :)